# MySQL select name from a table comparing attributes from to related tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Table 1

```
customer_name       restaurant_id         visits
shubham              1                     4
nayan                2                     6
```

Table 2

```
restaurant_id       restaurant_name
  1                       ramon hux
  2                       Mt.Pete's
```

Question: print the names of customers who have visits greater than 3 and restaurant name should have either a space or a single quote?

My Answer:

```
select customer_name from table1 where id=(select id from table2 
where restaurant_name like "% %" or restaurant_name like "%'%") and visits>3;
```

Issue: Subquery returns more than 1 row;

How do I get around this?

Comment: Use `in` instead of `=`.

Comment: Looks and smells like homework to me

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `IN` clause:

```
select customer_name from table1 where id IN (select id from table2 
where restaurant_name like "% %" or restaurant_name like "%'%") and visits>3;
```

Your subquery is returning more than 1 id hence your query is failing. You need to use IN to incorporate all the ids.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the sub query, You can do the same by using `JOIN`:

```
SELECT T1.customer_name 
FROM table1 T1
JOIN table2 T2 ON T2.id = T1.id
WHERE T1.visits > 3 AND (T2.restaurant_name LIKE "% %" OR T2.restaurant_name LIKE "%'%")
```